# Change local data json to remote data json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have working codes with local sample_data.son but I want to use remote sample_data.json. It's working but I didn't find true way. My code below.

```
- (void)generateData
{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add code here to do background processing
        //
      //
        NSError* err = nil;
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        companyData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_data" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* contents = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&err];
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
            // results of the background processing
            [contents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [data addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[obj objectForKey:@"first_name"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", [obj objectForKey:@"last_name"]]], @"DisplayText", [obj objectForKey:@"email"], @"DisplaySubText",obj,@"CustomObject", nil]];
                [companyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[obj objectForKey:@"company_name"], @"DisplayText", [obj objectForKey:@"address"], @"DisplaySubText",obj,@"CustomObject", nil]];
            }];
        });
    });
}

#pragma mark MPGTextField Delegate Methods

- (NSArray *)dataForPopoverInTextField:(MPGTextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:self.name]) {
        return data;
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:self.companyName]){
        return companyData;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldSelect:(MPGTextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)textField:(MPGTextField *)textField didEndEditingWithSelection:(NSDictionary *)result
{
    //A selection was made - either by the user or by the textfield. Check if its a selection from the data provided or a NEW entry.
    if ([[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] isEqualToString:@"NEW"]) {
        //New Entry
        [self.nameStatus setHidden:NO];
    }
    else{
        //Selection from provided data
        if ([textField isEqual:self.name]) {
            [self.nameStatus setHidden:YES];
            [self.web setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"web"]];
            [self.email setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"email"]];
            [self.phone1 setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"phone1"]];
            [self.phone2 setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"phone2"]];
        }
        [self.address setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"address"]];
        [self.state setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"state"]];
        [self.zip setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"zip"]];
        [self.companyName setText:[[result objectForKey:@"CustomObject"] objectForKey:@"company_name"]];
    }
}
```

I need only change to local parsing code to remote parsing code.

Also you can see original project with local json here
https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField

Comment: Suggestion: Make the code simpler, the statement beginning `[data addObject:` is 278 character and fairly incomprehensible. First there is unnecessary code, there is a literal syntax for arrays and dictionaries with simplifies creating them and finally some things such as combining first and last names are a good candidate for an intermediate statement. Code should be written for ease of understandability to the next developer, not the compiler.

Comment: have any idea ? still waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, an example of cleaner code as an answer for formatting.

Original:

```
[data addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[obj objectForKey:@"first_name"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", [obj objectForKey:@"last_name"]]], @"DisplayText", [obj objectForKey:@"email"], @"DisplaySubText",obj,@"CustomObject", nil]];
```

Re-formatted:

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", obj[@"first_name"], obj[@"last_name"]];
[data addObject: @{
                   @"DisplayText"    : fullName,
                   @"DisplaySubText" : obj[@"email"],
                   @"CustomObject"   : obj
                   }];
```